# UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted

Tags: python, pandas

Question: Using df_cleaned, create a dictionary called df_countries that keeps the unique values in the column "Country" as its keys and keeps the dataset for each country as its values. For example, df_countries["United States"] should reference the DataFrame containing the data for only the United States. The column "Country" should be dropped from this DataFrame.

I've tried: `df_countries = df_cleaned.set_index('Country',drop=True).T.to_dict('series')`

but it came out with an error:
`UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted.`

How to solve the warning? The data source is very big, but after I write this coding, it left only one data for each country. I have around 4 country names

**Data Source:**
[image: Data Source]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? `df_countries = df_cleaned.drop_duplicates('Country').set_index('Country').transpose().to_dict()`

Comment: No, it doesn't work, i think it will show more data when type in the keys, but using this coding, it will remove other data and keep the latest data

Comment: So do you need to not remove any rows?

Comment: yes, i think so, because only countries names are duplicating, but its corresponding data are unique

Comment: The keys have to be unique in a dictionary. Maybe you could put a list at each element of the dictionary, and put multiple records in each list?

Comment: Sorry, but can you show some example of coding?? can't figure out how to write it out

Comment: Actually, I think I've figured out a way to put a dataframe with multiple rows at each element of the index. Does this work? ```dictionary = dict(list(df_cleaned.groupby('a')))
for df in dictionary.values():
    df.drop('a', axis=1)```

Comment: i think this coding removed parts of the data, the output showed from row 22 to the last, but datas before row 22 are gone, besides the number of rows significantly reduced

Comment: I think the coding works, but the country name column didnt drop?? –